# Stored procedure for multiple insertions without existing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement where I have to insert multiple rows into different tables.

First I want to check whether the role exists in one table or not, then I have to insert the values into the `role` table then inserting into the related table.

Here my concern is I have to get the `roleid` if it is inserting and with that `roleid` only I will insert the values.

This all should be done in a single click and single stored procedure.

Waiting for reply.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Providing table structure(s) would help a lot.

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 and up, use [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) to perform a "query or insert" operation.

Answer (score 0):

Like @dasblinkenlight stated you can use the merge function to do an insert or update, so no need to cover that again.

If I understand your question correctly you want to insert multiple rows into different tables with a single stored procedure (something like persisting an entire object graph in one call). Extending on the example provided by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276847%28SQL.80%29.aspx) you can use the following sample code.

```
DECLARE @idoc int

DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)
SET @doc ='
<CustomersAndOrders>
<Customer CustomerID="VINET" ContactName="Paul Henriot">
   <Order CustomerID="VINET" EmployeeID="5" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00" />
</Customer>
<Customer CustomerID="LILAS" ContactName="Carlos Gonzlez">
   <Order CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00" />
</Customer>
</CustomersAndOrders>'

--Create an internal representation of the XML document.
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

-- Execute a SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.
INSERT INTO [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] ([Column1], [Column2])     
SELECT [CustomerID], [ContactName]
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/CustomersAndOrders/Customer',1)
WITH ([CustomerID] varchar(10), [ContactName] varchar(20))

INSERT INTO [YOUR_OTHER_TABLE_NAME] ([Column1], [Column2])     
SELECT [EmployeeID], [OrderDate]
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/CustomersAndOrders/Customer/Order',1)
WITH ([EmployeeID]  varchar(10), [OrderDate] varchar(20))
```

Comment: Happy to help, mark the answer as correct if it suits your needs (the tick beside the answer)